# React Performance Issues in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox

I'm experiencing some performance issues with a react application that I developed. These issues specifically (or most notably) occur with Firefox (both FF developer 77.0b7  and FF 76.0.1).

When using this application in Firefox, CPU usage gets extremely high, and my fans start spinning up to very high speeds. I get about 15-19fps in firefox according to the performance tools in FF. I get roughly 60fps in Chrome and Safari.

These issues occur when I begin typing into the input field, and get worse as the input gets longer (which makes sense)

The application is available here:
https://text-to-aura-generator.netlify.app/

Source code available here: https://github.com/paalwilliams/Text-to-Aura/tree/master/src

I'm almost certain that this is something I'm doing incorrectly, or that I've written the code inefficiently, but that isn't necessarily supported by the stark performance difference between browsers. Is chrome just that much better and handling react/constant rerenders?

I know that this is a broad question, but I honestly don't understand what is happening here, or necessarily how to troubleshoot it beyond the developer tools. Any input or thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your application is rendering too fast. In your particular case, there a few ways to improve that.

Every time you update the state, React needs to re-render your application, so updating the state within a loop is usually a bad idea.

Also, you are using `useState` 3 times, but only `colors` should be there, as `App` actually needs to re-render to reflect the changes there. The other two pieces of state (`text` and `hex`) are only being used to pass data from the `handleChange` to the callback inside `useEffect`.

You can restructure your code to:

- Avoid updating the state within a loop.
- Use a simple variable instead of state.
- Use `useCallback` to define a function with that logic that is not re-created on each render, as that forces `TextInput` to re-render as well.
- Throttle this callback using something like this:

  ```
  import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

  export function useThrottledCallback<A extends any[]>(
    callback: (...args: A) => void,
    delay: number,
    deps?: readonly any[],
  ): (...args: A) => void {
    const timeoutRef = useRef<number>();
    const callbackRef = useRef(callback);
    const lastCalledRef = useRef(0);

    // Remember the latest callback:
    //
    // Without this, if you change the callback, when setTimeout kicks in, it
    // will still call your old callback.
    //
    // If you add `callback` to useCallback's deps, it will also update, but it
    // might be called twice if the timeout had already been set.

    useEffect(() => {
      callbackRef.current = callback;
    }, [callback]);

    // Clear timeout if the components is unmounted or the delay changes:
    useEffect(() => window.clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current), [delay]);

    return useCallback((...args: A) => {
      // Clear previous timer:
      window.clearTimeout(timeoutRef.current);

      function invoke() {
        callbackRef.current(...args);
        lastCalledRef.current = Date.now();
      }

      // Calculate elapsed time:
      const elapsed = Date.now() - lastCalledRef.current;

      if (elapsed >= delay) {
        // If already waited enough, call callback:
        invoke();
      } else {
        // Otherwise, we need to wait a bit more:
        timeoutRef.current = window.setTimeout(invoke, delay - elapsed);
      }
    }, deps);
  }
  ```

If the reason to use `useEffect` is that you were not seeing the right values when updating `colors`, try using the version of `setState` that takes a callback rather then the new value, so instead of:

```
setColors([...colors, newColor]);
```

You would have:

```
setColors(prevColors => ([...prevColors , newColor]));
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll go ahead and include these changes and get back :)

Comment: I am still curious, however, as to why the performance difference between firefox and chrome is so stark. Is chrome really that much better at compiling and running js intensive apps?

It's worth noting that I've noticed this performance difference in other applications, too. I'm using the new facebook beta, which is all react, and its laggy and just generally slow in firefox, but noticeably better in Chrome.

Comment: @Paal As they use different engines, performance is going to be different as well, and there might be some areas where one is better than the other and some other areas where it is the other way around. That being said, with the issues your code had, it would have been slow as well on Chrome using a less powerful computer. Actually, you can use DevTools to throttle the CPU and see how your app behaves on slower devices. You can almost always run slow code without noticeable issues on a powerful enough hardware.

Answer (score 0):

The most common performance issues with react come from setting the state too many times since you're constantly re rendering the page and the elements within it.

Comment: I feel like setting state on an input change is a pretty reasonable amount of state change, no?